# Inserting cross-domain form, iframe or javascript ?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I need to produce a small script that users can insert in to their page/site, which creates/writes a satisfaction form. Once completed the form is submitted back to my server.

Would it be better to use javascript and append the form below the included `.js` file, append an iframe or do both? Both possibly for security issues?

Could I have some feedback from people who have previously achieved this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company I work for uses the iFrame method and it works great. We can inject CSS and JS callback parameters into the iFrame URL when required. We own hundreds of websites and they all share the same contact form, so we simply have one form which gets posted to one file regardless of the website on which it appears. Of course with the CSS injection it's easy for the form to look/feel like whatever website displays it at any given time.

Comment: The css part convinced me (not sure inject is the term), this was a main issu. Thank you.

Comment: Here are a couple examples: http://www.schools.com/contact-us  and http://www.onlineschools.com/contact-us . They both use the form on this page: http://contact.formfetch.com/